# Why is this code not passing the check challenge?

Tags: java, salesforce, apex, salesforce-lightning, lwc

I'm currently studying for my first superbadge, and it's been quite an adventure so far! However, I've hit a roadblock on the second task **(Automate record creation)** and could really use some assistance...

If anyone has any insights or tips regarding the second task, I would greatly appreciate your guidance. Feel free to check out the task details *(https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/superbadges/superbadge_apex)* for more context.

Thanks in advance for your help!

My code (Trigger Helper):

```
public with sharing class MaintenanceRequestHelper {
public static void createMaintenanceRequests(List<Case> newData, Map<Id, Case> oldData) {
    
    Set<Id> casesIds = new Set<Id>();
    for(Case c : newData){
        if(oldData.get(c.Id).Status != 'Closed' && c.Status == 'Closed'){
            if(c.Type == 'Repair' || c.Type == 'Routine Maintenance'){
                casesIds.add(c.Id);
            }
        }
    }
    
    Double minMaintenanceCycle = requestDue(casesIds);
    Integer daysToAdd = Math.round(minMaintenanceCycle);
    Date today = System.today();
    
    List<Case> newCases = new List<Case>();
    
    for(Case cc : [SELECT Id, ParentId, Vehicle__c, Vehicle__r.Name, (SELECT Equipment__c, Maintenance_Request__c, Quantity__c FROM Equipment_Maintenance_Items__r) FROM Case WHERE Id IN :casesIds]){
        Case nc = new Case();
        nc.ParentId = cc.Id;
        nc.Status = 'New';
        nc.Subject = 'Maintenance Request for ' + cc.Vehicle__r.Name;
        nc.Type = 'Routine Maintenance';
        nc.Vehicle__c = cc.Vehicle__c;
       
        for (Equipment_Maintenance_Item__c eq : cc.Equipment_Maintenance_Items__r) {
            Equipment_Maintenance_Item__c newEq = new Equipment_Maintenance_Item__c();
            newEq.Equipment__c = eq.Equipment__c;
            newEq.Maintenance_Request__c = eq.Maintenance_Request__c;
            newEq.Quantity__c = eq.Quantity__c;
            nc.Equipment_Maintenance_Items__r.add(newEq);
        }

        nc.Date_Reported__c = today;
        nc.Date_Due__c = today.addDays(daysToAdd);
        newCases.add(nc);
    }

    try {
        insert newCases;
    } catch (DMLException e) {
        System.debug(e);
    }

}

public static Double requestDue(Set<Id> validIds){
    List<Case> cases = [SELECT (SELECT Equipment__c, Maintenance_Request__c, Quantity__c FROM Equipment_Maintenance_Items__r) FROM Case WHERE Id IN :validIds];
    
    Set<Id> equipIds = new Set<Id>();
    for (Case c : cases) {
        for (Equipment_Maintenance_Item__c emi : c.Equipment_Maintenance_Items__r) {
            equipIds.add(emi.Equipment__c);
        }
    }
    List<Double> maintenanceCycles = new List<Double>();
    List<Product2> equipmentList = [SELECT Maintenance_Cycle__c FROM Product2 WHERE Id IN :equipIds];
    for (Product2 p : equipmentList) {
        maintenanceCycles.add(p.Maintenance_Cycle__c);
    }

    maintenanceCycles.sort();
    return maintenanceCycles[0];
}
}
```

Trigger itself:

```
trigger MaintenanceRequest on Case (before update, after update) {
if(Trigger.isUpdate && Trigger.isAfter){
    MaintenanceRequestHelper.createMaintenanceRequests(Trigger.New, Trigger.OldMap);
}
}
```

I got the error **out of bounds** from the maintenanceCycles (A list of Double values), but it doesn't make sense for me...

ERROR:

There was an unexpected error in your org which is preventing this assessment check from completing: System.DmlException: Update failed. First exception on row 0 with id 5008b00002KYlQbAAL; first error: CANNOT_INSERT_UPDATE_ACTIVATE_ENTITY, MaintenanceRequest: execution of AfterUpdate caused by: System.ListException: List index out of bounds: 1 Class.MaintenanceRequestHelper.requestDue: line 64, column 1 Class.MaintenanceRequestHelper.createMaintenanceRequests: line 13, column 1            Trigger.MaintenanceRequest: line 3, column 1: []*

Answer (score 0):

did you check the return property: maintenanceCycles have any record inside before returning the first element in the list?